# Creating Combinations of Elements

Tags: php, laravel, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I want to create product option system. I have a form look like this:

[![Sample image][2]][2]
<sub>(source: [resmim.net](https://resmim.net/f/vUxZM0.jpg?nocache))</sub>

Form's inputs are tag inputs. First input is option name. When you put any option name the new tag input added in the form.

**My problem:**

I can't create combinations in controller because the inputs name an quantity will be random.

**Current Code:**

I found this code but i cant customize it for my system

First inputs code id:

when i post data goes to controller post it another blade. i incude this in my page

In controller

```
 public function sendd(Request $request){
    $a = $request['data'];

    return view ('system.modules.variations', compact('a'));
}
```

In another blade

```
@if(!empty($a))
@foreach($a as $b)
    <label class="sr-only" for="{{$b}}"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{$b}}" name="{{$b}}" data-role="tagsinput" id="{{$b}}"/></br>
@endforeach
```

@endif

if will create new tag inputs which i can add the variations eg : Red, Blue

after i send form to another controller

```
 $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',

            url:'/mauuu',

            data: $("#addpro").serialize(),

            success:function(){
                
            }
        });
        
    });
```

I send data like this but i can't create combinations:

[![][1]][1]
<sub>(source: [resmim.net][3])</sub>

Okey I adding my all codes

This is my blade form

```
<form class="floating-labels m-t-40" id="addpro">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" required>
                                    <span class="bar"></span>
                                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group m-b-5">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"  name="description" id="description" required></textarea>
                                    <span class="bar"></span>
                                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="bullet" id="bullet" required></textarea>
                                    <span class="bar"></span>
                                    <label for="bullet">Box</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                    <a onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-small" id="btn-x">Add variations</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="options" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sku" id="sku" required>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <label for="sku">Sku</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" required>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <label for="price">Price</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" id="barcode" required>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <label for="barcode">Barcode</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rprice" id="rprice" required>
                                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                                <label for="rprice">Refence Price</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group m-b-40">

                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="option" data-role="tagsinput" id="option"/>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 asd">
                                            @include('system.modules.variations')
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-submit">Submit</button>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    @include('system.modules.variants')
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

and ajax post

```
       <script>
    $('#option').change(function(){
    var data = $('#option').tagsinput('items');

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',

            url:'/mauu',

            data:{ _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', data:data},

            success:function(returnedHtml){
                $(".asd").html(returnedHtml);

            }

        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(".btn-submit").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',

            url:'/mauuu',

            data: $("#addpro").serialize(),

            success:function(){

            }
        });

    });


</script>
```

this is the variations blade

```
    @if(!empty($a))
@foreach($a as $b)
    <label class="sr-only" for="{{$b}}"></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{$b}}" name="{{$b}}" data-role="tagsinput" id="{{$b}}"/></br>
@endforeach
    @endif
```

And this is my controller

```
 public function sendd(Request $request){
    $a = $request['data'];

    return view ('system.modules.variations', compact('a'));
}

public function sent(Request $request){

  foreach ($request as $req ){
      $option = explode(',', $request['option']);

      $inputs = explode(',', $request->$option); // eg ['Color','Size']
      dd($inputs);
  }
```

Submit button's function is sent
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41o1Z.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8oW5.jpg
[3]: https://web.archive.org/web/20190718012105/https://resmim.net/f/NffcWv.jpg

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by *create combinations*? Maybe by adding sample input and expected output would help

Comment: i am sorry my bad english :(  

for example T-shirt

size S,M,L
color Red, Blue 
combinations 
S-Red
M-Red
L-Red
S-Blue
M-Blue
L-Blue

Comment: can you show us the result of you current code ?

Comment: This code is not working correct. it's result is null. Because $provided  and foreach are changable in my system but on this it's stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have a **fixed** input which represents the other inputs.

For example `inputs` then using the input names given in `inputs` field (in your example they are `Color` and `Size`) you can adjust your current code to use them. For example to get you started:

```
$inputs = explode(',', $request->input('inputs', '')); // eg ['Color','Size']

// now foreach input in inputs, create new input controls combinations
$props = [];
foreach($inputs as $input)
{
    $input_key = strtolower($input);
    if ( !$request->has($input_key) ) continue;
    $input_values = explode(',', $request->input($input_key));
    $props[$input_key] = $input_values;
}
$combinations = make_combinations($props); // NOTE this is destructive, it will destroy the current $props array, copy it if you need it
// now you can handle the combinations as you want
```

Then have a utility recursive function `make_combinations()` (you can make it a controller method if you need to and call as `$this->make_combinations($props)`  also update below code from `make_combinations(..)` to `$this->make_combinations(..)` ) for example:

```
// adjust this function to return the information you need
// right now it returns only the names of the combinations
// adjust or add comment on having more information, eg price
function make_combinations($props)
{
    if ( empty($props) ) return [];
    $keys = array_keys($props);
    $key = $keys[0];
    $values = $props[$key];
    unset($props[$key]);  // this prop is being processed, remove it
    $rest =  make_combinations($props); // process the rest
    if ( empty($values) ) return $rest;
    if ( empty($rest) ) return $values;
    $combinations = []
    foreach($rest as $comb)
    {
        foreach($values as $value)
        {
           $combinations[] = $value . '-' . $comb;
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for time. I changed my input name 

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/8GrsNX.jpg[/IMG]

And Code 

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/ysHmr7.jpg[/IMG]

dd($combinations); gives to

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/JSgsgc.jpg[/IMG]

And Post values 

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/THKmeg.jpg[/IMG]

And $inputs 

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/qQTGDn.jpg[/IMG]

[IMG]https://resmim.net/f/TJMK8C.jpg[/IMG]

Color option is none. I can't do it i m sorry

Comment: you cant have `make_combinations` function **inside** controller mthod. Better add it as another controller method and adjust to call as `$this->make_combinations($props);` Please update your question with the code you have so far (dont use images) and I will try to provide updated answer

Comment: Also it seems you are using **same fixed input name** `inputs` for all your inputs. This is wrong. The name `inputs` should be used **only** for the intial options (eg Color, Size) the rest specific inputs shiould have their own input names (eg `color[]`, `size[]` and so on..). Please update your question with the code you have so far so I can try to help you

Comment: I updated my question. And i am sorry my bag English

Comment: @Energy40, please add all your code (like the code you sent in  the images), so I can try to help. Else I can only provide bits of functionality here and there and you will have to combine it yourself to make it work

Comment: @Energy40, no I mean the code you sent in  the images in your other comment. Please provide the whole controller and blade view that you currently have (and any other code that is related to the functionality). it seems you need help to set it up. My answer as it stands solves your problem but you need to know how to combine the parts I provided to solve your problem. it seems you can;'t do that so I will need all the relevant code you have in order to guide you through step-by-step

Comment: I'm trying but system gives error can you give me email address?

Comment: @Energy40, sorry cant give email address.

Comment: Site gives to me this error when i try add codes


Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: Thank You So Much. I Modified Your Code And It's Work